# Adding search box to Leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, search

Consider the example in the following link for [Folium](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium): [**US Employment visualization per county**](http://bl.ocks.org/wrobstory/5609889).

The result looks like what you see below:

[image]

I would like to add a search box to it to be able to search by city, and have the visualization zoom in and/or center around it.

How can I go about adding such search box to it, perhaps by adding functionality in the HTML file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use the [Leaflet search control](http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/). It allows you to insert a search widget on your map, search by place names around the world (see [Nominatim example](http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/geocoding-nominatim.html)), and once a place is selected, zoom/center your map to that place location.

[image]

In the [Leaflet search's GitHub website](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search#examples) you find examples on how to add the control to your leaflet map.