# leaflet search control not showing up in geodjango app

Tags: leaflet, javascript, html, geodjango, search-window

I have a very basic geodjango app and I am trying to enable search control on it. I have found this question [Adding a search box to a Leaflet.js example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130623/adding-a-search-box-to-a-leaflet-js-example) and the link brought me to what it seems like to be the correct page. I am trying to follow the simple example http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/simple.html.

steps so far

1. downloaded the code https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search#examples
2. added the leaflet-search.css and leaflet-search.js (from the src) folder to my html document.

Here is my entire html document code

```
<html>
{% load static %}
{% load leaflet_tags %}
<head>
    {% leaflet_js %}
    {% leaflet_css %}
    <title>Our Home</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #gis {width: 80%;height:500px;}
    </style>
    <link rel=stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'search/src/leaflet-search.css' %}">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'dist/leaflet.ajax.js' %}" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'search/src/leaflet-search.js' %}" > </script>

</head>
<body>
<h3>
    Maps are cool
</h3>
<br>
<div id="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function our_layers(map,options){

        var OpenTopoMap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 17,
            attribution: 'Map data: &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)'
        });

        var OpenStreetMap_BlackAndWhite = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.wmflabs.org/bw-mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        });

        var counties = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'county' %}",{
            style: function colors(feature){
                switch(feature.properties.namelsad){
                    case 'Deal borough':
                        return{
                            color: 'orange',
                            fillOpacity: 0.8
                        };
                    break;
                    case 'Asbury Park city':
                        return{
                            color: 'purple',
                            fillOpacity: 0.8
                        };
                    break;

                }

            },
            onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.namelsad.toString())
            }
        });
        counties.addTo(map);

        var incidences = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'incidences' %}",{

             onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name.toString())
            }
        });
        incidences.addTo(map);



    var data = [
        {"loc":[41.575330,13.102411], "title":"aquamarine"},
        {"loc":[41.575730,13.002411], "title":"black"},
        {"loc":[41.807149,13.162994], "title":"blue"},
        {"loc":[41.507149,13.172994], "title":"chocolate"},
        {"loc":[41.847149,14.132994], "title":"coral"},
        {"loc":[41.219190,13.062145], "title":"cyan"},
        {"loc":[41.344190,13.242145], "title":"darkblue"},
        {"loc":[41.679190,13.122145], "title":"Darkred"},
        {"loc":[41.329190,13.192145], "title":"Darkgray"},
        {"loc":[41.379290,13.122545], "title":"dodgerblue"},
        {"loc":[41.409190,13.362145], "title":"gray"},
        {"loc":[41.794008,12.583884], "title":"green"},
        {"loc":[41.805008,12.982884], "title":"greenyellow"},
        {"loc":[41.536175,13.273590], "title":"red"},
        {"loc":[41.516175,13.373590], "title":"rosybrown"},
        {"loc":[41.506175,13.273590], "title":"royalblue"},
        {"loc":[41.836175,13.673590], "title":"salmon"},
        {"loc":[41.796175,13.570590], "title":"seagreen"},
        {"loc":[41.436175,13.573590], "title":"seashell"},
        {"loc":[41.336175,13.973590], "title":"silver"},
        {"loc":[41.236175,13.273590], "title":"skyblue"},
        {"loc":[41.546175,13.473590], "title":"yellow"},
        {"loc":[41.239190,13.032145], "title":"white"}
    ];

    var markersLayer = new L.LayerGroup();  //layer contain searched elements

    map.addLayer(markersLayer);

    var controlSearch = new L.Control.Search({
        position:'topright',
        layer: markersLayer,
        initial: false,
        zoom: 12,
        marker: false
    });

    map.addControl( controlSearch );

    ////////////populate map with markers from sample data
    for(i in data) {
        var title = data[i].title,  //value searched
            loc = data[i].loc,      //position found
            marker = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(loc), {title: title} );//se property searched
        marker.bindPopup('title: '+ title );
        markersLayer.addLayer(marker);
    };


}
</script>
{% leaflet_map "gis" callback="window.our_layers" %}
</body>
</html>
```

this is the app below there are zero errors in the console but there is no search control box that appears

[image]

any ideas on what my problem could be?

As you can see below the div element thats holding the search box, exists on the top right and when I highlight it it highlights where the search box is but it does not show up. and if you look at the properties in in the div class for the search box where ever it says `display:` it follows with it a `none`

**UPDATE**

when I change `style="display: none; max-width: 736.797px;"` to

`style="display: true; max-width: 736.797px;"`

the search box shows up in the web map. so how do I enable that to be turned on from when I load the webpage

```
<input class="search-input" type="text" size="9" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="Search..." id="searchtext9" style="display: true; max-width: 736.797px;">
```

[image]

pretty stuck on how else to approach this problem. if anyone has any solutions or hints

**update based on comments**

1/2. I have not touched any css other than what is displayed on this question. if you mean leaflet-search.css of rows 8-10 this is what it is `background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;`

3. when I click on where the control search is this is what shows in the rules tab

   element {
   }
   .leaflet-right .leaflet-control {
       margin-right: 10px;
   }
   .leaflet-top .leaflet-control {
       margin-top: 10px;
   }
   .leaflet-right .leaflet-control {
       float: right;
   }
   .leaflet-popup-pane, .leaflet-control {
       cursor: auto;
   }
   .leaflet-control {
       float: left;
       clear: both;
   }
   .leaflet-control {
       position: relative;
       z-index: 800;
       pointer-events: visiblePainted;
       pointer-events: auto;
   }
   .leaflet-top, .leaflet-bottom {
       pointer-events: none;
   }
   .leaflet-container {
       font: 12px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
   .leaflet-grab {
       cursor: -webkit-grab;
       cursor: -moz-grab;
   }

---

this code

`<input class="search-input" type="text" size="9" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="Search..." id="searchtext9" style="display: none;">`

when I change to `display: block` the search box shows up

Comment: If you look at the inspector tab of the [tutorial](http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/simple.html) you linked to, you can see that the element with class `search-cancel` also has `style="display:none;" there. So this is likely not the issue. (See this screenshot: https://postimg.cc/image/bs54zvavl/)

Comment: dang, okay well when I change up on the web browser it actually displays the search box. what else could it be? I am trying to follow the directions exactly as they are...

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), `true` is not an available value for `display`. So this can't really be it... Do you have a live demo of your app?

Comment: okay so even stranger how that works

Comment: no its only a small local project (actually my first real web project)

Comment: Looks similar to this GH issue: https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/issues/169 The OP closed the issue, but never said if it worked for them.

Comment: okay so what would be the next step in the debugging

Comment: In general, we should look at all the places that modify/influence CSS in one way or another.

(1) What about the [internal CSS](https://vineetgupta22.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/inline-vs-internal-vs-external-css/) you are using in row 8-10?
(2) Have you made any other CSS modifications somewhere?
(3) What does the "Rules" tab give you, when you click on the search button in the Inspector? (In my Firefox it is on the right side of the Inspector.)

Comment: @Stefan_Fairphone check edits

Comment: Let's really go to chat now: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81295/discussion-between-stefan-fairphone-and-ziggy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so after troubleshooting in the comments and in [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81295/discussion-between-stefan-fairphone-and-ziggy) we found out that the relevant `<div>` was always there, but it had 0x0 px. The magnifying glass (search icon) simply was not displayed. It is necessary, however, because it triggers the search bar to be displayed. No search icon = nowhere to click on = no search bar.

Now the search icon is a `.png` file that is referenced in [`leaflet-search.css`](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/blob/f6ebac21774aeac953d3552dd667a6230f14617c/src/leaflet-search.css#L69)
. Only the leaflet js and css were copied over to the django project file so there was no image icon able to be loaded. The search control plugin was re-downloaded and all the files were placed in the django static folder. Eventually, it turned out, that the map couldn't find the CSS file because of some missing quotes and a wrong path. This is the correct `<link>` for the HTML `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "leaflet-search-master/src/leaflet-search.css" %}">
```